# is it possible to change direction of a splide slider in responsive?

Tags: html, responsive, direction

is it possible to change direction of a splide slider in responsive? when i want to change the direction of the thumnail slider in responsive the slider crash.

```
 var secondarySlider = new Splide("#splidev2", {
    direction: "ttb",
    type: "loop",
    height: "100%",
    fixedWidth: 100,
    fixedHeight: 100,
    isNavigation: true,
    gap: 10,
    pagination: false,
    arrows: true,
    focus: "center",
    updateOnMove: true,
    rewind: false,
    breakpoints:{
      1199: {
        perPage: 2,
        gap    : '1.5rem',
        height : '24rem',
      },
    991: {
            direction: "ltr",
        
    },
    
  }).mount();
  var primarySlider = new Splide("#splide", {
    type: "fade",
    pagination: false,
    cover: true,
    arrows: false,

  });
  primarySlider.sync(secondarySlider).mount();
```

https://splidejs.com/guides/options/#direction

Answer (score -2):

From the given documentation I got this = "*You can update responsive options by breakpoints or by passing an object to Splide#options...*"
You can use **Slide#options**, if breakpoints not working.